# Get domain controller address by netbios name

Tags: node.js, active-directory, domaincontroller, fqdn, netbios

I am trying to authenticate a user to an **Active Directory** in node.js.
By using the `npm` library "*active directory*" or "*ad*" I can do this.
My problem is to get the fully qualified name of the domain controller from the NetBios Name (NT format).

What I get:  `domain\user (e.g. sales\tom)`
What I need: `sales.mycompany.com`

> Is there any library doing sort of a `nslookup`?

Comment: Have you tried reading the UPN (User Principal Name) value (*I don't know how it is done in node.js*)!

Comment: Is the computer you are doing this from joined to the same domain?

Comment: Using UPN works but I need a login based on the format domain\username.
The computer is not in the same domain. I want to be able to authenticate a user from a different domain within the company as each department has their own domain.